# Why is Apollo using an older GraphQL query and not returning a supplied field

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

So i've got two GraphQL queries which im using with React-Apollo:

```
query query1($id: String, $offset: Int, $limit: Int) {
  item: data(id: $id, offset: $offset, limit: $limit) {
    key
    name
    description
  }

query query2($id: String) {
  item: data(id: $id) {
    key
    name
    description
    score
  }
```

I call query1 using `client.query` and it works correctly

I then call query2 using `client.query` again, but this time, the `score` field doesn't return to me. I can see it being returned in the network response, but when I try to log it to console for example, all I get is the `key, name, description` fields. I've tried setting the cachePolicy to `no-cache` but it just returns the same thing

Why is it doing this?

```
  async doSomething() {
    let data = await this.props.client.query({
      query: query1,
      variables: { id: id },
      fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
    });
    this.myFunc(data.data.item)
  }


  myFunc = data => {
    console.log(data)
  };
```

Comment: show more code? use different aliases? IMHO not a cache issue

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: this is working part ;)  - place second query call in `doSomething` after the first one ?

Comment: Ya does it work if you make `query2` without making `query1`?